# Search for educational articles

Tags: secondary-education, education-research

I am looking for articles in French preferably (or in English otherwise, but my english is bad..) on the following topics:

- study of assessments made in class after a problem;
- phase of conclusion of a problem;
- institutionalization of problems.

I am already familiar with the IREM site (French site), but I did not find articles there specific to the phases of conclusion of the problems. This is part of a thesis, and I am currently a young teacher in high school.

Thank you in advance for your suggestions, good day.

Comment: Welcome! Have you searched Semantic scholar, Google scholar and your university library system for these, in French and English? (And in other languages you manage to read; probably other romance languages.)

Comment: What do you mean by "problem"?  A mathematical problem ("How many marbles are there in all?") or a teaching problem ("My students are inattentive.")?

Comment: The world needs Esperanto.